# why I donot need to start ssh-agent and I can connect to remote git repo without user/password?

Tags: ssh-agent

1. I have create private/publich key pair by ssh-keygen command line.
2. I have already paste the content of ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub to github account
3. I have already manually start ssh-agent and add the private key by followinng command lines:
   3.1 $ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   3.2 $ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
4. so I can use git clone and other git command lines without user/passworld
5. after reboot the linux system, I found no ssh-agent process but I can still use git command line to interact with github aacount. WHY? I see lot of article saying that you must start ssh-agent ervery time or automatically start ssh-agent. confusing...

would you please help to explan the reason.
the OS of my linux server is Centos stream 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a passphrase on your private key, ssh-agent is not necessary. –
1615903
Feb 14, 2017 at 6:36